# numpy array printing in desired manner

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using numpy array to fetch values from file and do calculations. The final output is like this 
`('I', 10031, 'GASAS.SW', 2024, 23067, -501, -6760.1, 1, 125 )` 
But i need it to be printed like this 
`I 10031 GASAS.SW 2024 23067 -501 -6760.1 1 125`

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Comment: In SOF you need to add what you have tried with your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = ('I', 10031, 'GASAS.SW', 2024, 23067, -501, -6760.1, 1, 125 )
print " ".join([str(i) for i in x])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert all integers to strings while converting your data (of type `tuple`) to `list` and then apply `join()` function as follows:

```
data = ('I', 10031, 'GASAS.SW', 2024, 23067, -501, -6760.1, 1, 125 )
res = ' '.join([str(item) for item in data])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
'I 10031 GASAS.SW 2024 23067 -501 -6760.1 1 125'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer